# How to install JBoss7 to run as a service?

Tags: jboss

How to run Jboss (preferably Jboss 7) as a service on Ubuntu? I can run Jboss using its sh file e.g. sh /jboss/bin/run.sh. But I can not monitor it like tomcat /etc/init.d/tomcat start|stop|restart.

Comment: This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: @Ringtail I disagree. It's a useful question to me.

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss 5 and 6 you can find in the `bin` directory proper service scripts, for example `jboss_init_redhat.sh`. These script can be easily adopted to run in Debian system.

But with JBoss 7 there is no such script. I think that you have to adopt for example start script from earlier JBoss version or create your own.

There is some documentation about running JBoss as service (boy not for JBoss 7):

[StartJBossOnBootWithLinux](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/StartJBossOnBootWithLinux)

---

Small update:

In JBoss EAP 6 version you can find init script in bin/init.d directory.